# Flutter setState 3 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found error

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-state

on Button click, I trying to call setState but VScode generates a bug like below.
Its Stateful widget and VScode suggested that `setState(mounted, setState, fn);`

[image: 1]

```
 Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
     children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.rounded_corner,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedStock--;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    Text(selectedStock.toString()),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.rounded_corner,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // setState(mounted, setState, fn);
                        setState(() {
                          selectedStock++;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: restart vs code and try?

Comment: why you had ``setState(mounted, setState, fn);``?

Comment: I don't know, when I used to write setState then click enter setState((){}) appears. Now setState(mounted, setState, fn); i restarted but result is same

Comment: it might be some sort of issue with either of the vs code extension

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It turned out that the problem was this import:

```
import 'package:html_editor_enhanced/utils/utils.dart';
```

It defines the following method:

```
void setState(
    bool mounted, void Function(Function()) setState, void Function() fn) {
  if (mounted) {
    setState.call(fn);
  }
}
```

which conflicts with the one defined in Flutter `framework` file.

In my case it turned out I didn't even need that import so I just deleted it. If you do need this import you can give it a prefix:

```
import 'package:html_editor_enhanced/utils/utils.dart' as utils;
```

This way you will call it's methods through the prefix and call Flutters `setState()` directly.

More info on import prefixes: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility

Comment: This worked for me: I deleted this import 'package:html_editor_enhanced/utils/utils.dart'; it worked after